# What are the stages of traversals of the Mediterranean Sea?

Tags: classical-antiquity, ships, mediterranean

Different tribes and nations have existed all around the Mediterranean sea in the bronze age and later. They would know their land-neighbors, and may have communicated and traded with each other directly via sea travel (during calm summer months, as soon as seafaring was advanced enough). Yet they would not have been a military threat to each other as long as the sea travel was too risky and expensive, compared to campaigns over land. So I imagine that for some time, the Mediterranean allowed trade but blocked conquest, until a time when conquest became viable due to ship technology allowing safe travel of armies. The question is when (with what nation) those dynamics changed.

I imagine that in prehistory, rafts and canoes only followed the shorelines at best, but at some point in antiquity, it must have become common to cross the Mediterranean sea at different points every year for communication, raids and trade (at Gibraltar and Sicily mostly supposedly), maybe during the calm season only at first.

Similarly, I imagine that for waging war, there must have been evolutionary stages of shipbuilding that allowed to cross the Mediterranean en masse with an armada, not too expensively, and without risking not being able to return. I imagine during the Greco-Persian wars, technology was not advanced enough for direct (non-shore-following) warfare across the sea, while during the Punic wars it was advanced enough.

So are there in literature known stages for when the Mediterranean became traversable for different purposes? Possibly with the required advances in shipbuilding and navigation required?

The purpose of my question is to understand 1. when knowledge transfer became reliable across the Mediterranean and 2. when countries on the other side become viable military targets / significant military threats, compared to neighboring territories reachable on land.

I have trouble finding details about bronze age sea trade routes. It seems established that tin got from the British isles to middle east, but other than crossing the English Channel, I am not sure where sea-faring ships were used as opposed to river-boats.

Update1: as an example Wikipedia has a [map of Phoenician trade routes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenicia), but it's not clear if the Phoenicians also had a navy to attack lands along those routes, in particular without following the directions with the ships (As opposed to conquering North Africa by land, and establishing other colonies without need for warfare).

Update2:
Some websites declare: "The Phoenicians were famed in antiquity for their ship-building skills, and they were credited with inventing the keel, the battering ram on the bow, and caulking between planks". So it seems that before the Phoenicians, only near-shore travels were common, and at the end of their period, seafaring was advanced enough to cross the Mediterranean with more safety in greater number, but maybe there was no definite time when such traversals became significant for military conquest. It would still be interesting to know which nation first became an existential threat to all other nations in the Mediterranean due to seafaring.

Update3: The sea peoples mentioned in wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_Peoples as: "The Sea Peoples are a purported seafaring confederation that attacked ancient Egypt and other regions of the East Mediterranean prior to and during the Late Bronze Age collapse". But it does not indicate where those were based, nor what ships they used, nor whether their ships could travel away from the coast: "The Sea Peoples remain unidentified in the eyes of most modern scholars".

Udate4:
It would seem that a safe upper bound would be the roman conquests of Sicily in 241 BC and then Carthage itself in 146 BC, at which time any nation bordering the Mediterranean would likely have to consider defenses against a roman invasion via the sea.

Comment: The bronze Age starts roughly about 3000 BCE around the Mediterranean and, due to the extreme rarity of the required tin, required long distance trade. This long distance trade was almost certainly by sea, so overseas trade likely precedes the development of both cuneiform and hieroglyphic writing.

Comment: This looks relevant: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/1095-9270.12155

Comment: @tkruse - at least in my experience, you'll improve your chances of getting a good answer if everything you know is in the question and not in the comments.  Also might help to clarify which question you want answers to.  Are you looking for a formal theory of maritime travel, or the rates of communication/knowledge transfer (which may not be maritime), or for military transport (which is definitely different than communication)?  Napoleon found ways to project military force without sea control.

Comment: I wouldn't have phrased it this way, but I think the answer is probably a recapitulation of the technology of maritime shipbuilding technology and navigation technology.  I don't know the answer, but I used to know most of it, so it is answerable.

Comment: I was expecting to have a table of 3-5 dates with known repeated exploits of trade and conquest that involved crossing the Mediterranean, ideally also with the technologies that made this possible if lack of technology has been the issue before. The contents indicate some early bronze age seafaring capabilities on longboat variants towards islands. So now I mostly need to know who started moving armies of conquest across the Mediterranean.

Comment: @tkruse, please don't update the question in comments.  Update the question so that it stands alone without reference to comments.

Comment: The biggest enigma of this sort is how Australia was populated by humans approximately 50,000 years ago. Geology shows that they had to cross hundreds miles of open sea. And the evidence of the presence of humans so long ago is indisputable. This suggests that overseas travel was practiced VERY long before history begins, and unfortunately there is no information about how could it be performed.

Comment: @Brian: thanks for the excellent reference: it exactly addresses the question and confirms my comment that seafaring goes back to Paleolith, and predates by far not only writing and metallurgy but even agriculture.

Comment: @Alex Was it really hundreds miles of open sea 50000 years ago? This map from wiki https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b7/Sunda_shelf.jpg shows the gap of about 90 km near Timor. But this is not a fantastic distance to cross even with no sophisticated seafaring and the land on the other side would be visible from the mountains at Timor (so it wouldn't be a leap of faith to go there)

Comment: @OON: You should not look at the modern map. The map substantially changed in 50,000 years. I do not remember the exact source where this is analysed, but it is probably not hard to find. Also look at the reference which Brian gave; it is very informative. It explains some modern discoveries in Mediterranean which indicate that seafaring as almost as old as modern human species:-)

Comment: I suspect this may be too broad to answer on SE (and I'm not entirely clear what you mean by "stages of traversals" in this context).  However, the Late Neolithic and Early Bronze Age [Cycladic Culture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycladic_culture) probably represents some of the earliest evidence we have for "seafaring", where vessels were likely to be out-of-sight of land for prolonged periods. I suspect that would therefore probably be one of the first "stages" you are looking for.

Comment: Much later, we have the late Bronze Age shipwrecks at [Cape Gelidonya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cape_Gelidonya#Bronze_Age_shipwreck) and [Uluburun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uluburun_shipwreck) (and also the [recent discovery](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00310328.2019.1579467) of a rather earlier Bronze Age shipwreck) which all seem to have been *capable* of crossing the Mediterranean, although they were probably normally used as coastal traders.

Comment: @OON: Perhaps the data I mentioned are out of date. Here is a modern research on the question, with maps: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0047248418302136

Answer (score 2):

**Dugout canoe**

[Dugout canoe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dugout_canoe)

> Dugouts are the oldest boat type archaeologists have found, dating back about 8,000 years to the Neolithic Stone Age

**Pesse canoe**

[Pesse canoe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pesse_canoe)

> The Pesse canoe is believed to be the world's oldest known boat, and certainly the oldest known canoe. Carbon dating indicates that the boat was constructed during the early mesolithic period between 8040 BCE and 7510 BCE

**Uru boat**

[Indus Valley to Mesopotamia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boat#History)

> Boats played an important role in the commerce between the Indus Valley Civilization and Mesopotamia.[13]

[Uru boat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uru_(boat))

> The Uru, or "Fat Boat", is a generic name for large Dhow-type wooden ships made by asharis in Beypore, a village south of Kozhikode, Kerala, in the southwestern coast of India.

> This type of boat has been used by the Arabs since ancient times as trading vessels, and even now, urus are being manufactured and exported to Arab nations from Beypore. These boats used to be built of several types of wood, the main one being teak. The teak was taken from Nilambur forests in earlier times, but now imported Malaysian teak is used. A couple of boat-building yards can still be found near the Beypore port

[Herodotus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boat#History)

> The historians Herodotus, Pliny the Elder and Strabo record the use of boats for commerce, travel, and military purposes.[14]

**Hjortspring boat**

[Hjortspring boat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norway#Bronze_Age)

> Thousands of rock carvings from this period depict ships, and the large stone burial monuments known as stone ships, suggest that ships and seafaring played an important role in the culture at large. The depicted ships most likely represent sewn plank built canoes used for warfare, fishing and trade. These ship types may have their origin as far back as the neolithic period and they continue into the Pre-Roman Iron Age, as exemplified by the Hjortspring boat.[42]

**Praise of the two lands**

[Praise of the two lands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Praise_of_the_Two_Lands_(ship))

> "Praise of the Two Lands", appearing in an inscription (c. 2613 BCE) of boat building projects of Egyptian pharaoh Sneferu, is the first reference to a ship bearing a name.

**Sealand dynasty**

[Sealand dynasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sealand_Dynasty)

> The Sealand Dynasty, (URU.KÙKI[nb 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dugout_canoe)[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pesse_canoe)) or the 2nd Dynasty of Babylon (although it was independent of Amorite-ruled Babylon), very speculatively c. 1732–1460 BC (short chronology), is an enigmatic series of kings attested to primarily in laconic references in the king lists A and B, and as contemporaries recorded on the Assyrian Synchronistic king list A.117. The dynasty, which had broken free of the short lived, and by this time crumbling Babylonian Empire, was named for the province in the far south of Mesopotamia

**Sea peoples**

[Sea peoples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_Peoples)

> The Sea Peoples are a purported seafaring confederation that attacked ancient Egypt and other regions of the East Mediterranean prior to and during the Late Bronze Age collapse (1200–900 BCE)

**Battle against Sherden sea pirates**

[Ramesses II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramesses_II#Battle_against_Sherden_sea_pirates)

> In his second year, Ramesses II decisively defeated the Sherden sea pirates who were wreaking havoc along Egypt's Mediterranean coast by attacking cargo-laden vessels travelling the sea routes to Egypt.[20]

**My answer**

I think we can clearly see the history of Ship building is far larger than something created by only Phoenicians.

However is there any truth to Phoenicians being linked to large scale seafaring?

**Phoenicians**

[Early historic references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherden#Early_historical_references)

> Years later, other waves of Sea People, the Sherden included, were defeated by Merneptah, son of Ramesses II, and Ramesses III. An Egyptian work written around 1100 BC, the Onomasticon of Amenope, documents the presence of the Sherden in Palestine.[12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aboriginal_Australians#Origins) After being defeated by Pharaoh Ramsses III, they, along with other "Sea Peoples", would be allowed to settle in that territory, subject to Egyptian rule.

> The Italian orientalist Giovanni Garbini identified the territory settled by the Sherden in Northern Palestine as the one occupied, according to the Bible, by the Israelite tribe of Zebulun, where also appears a village named Sared.[13][14][15]

So, who are the Phoenicians?

**Phoenicians**

[Phoenician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenician)

> Phoenicia (/fəˈnɪʃə/;[5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norway#Bronze_Age) from Ancient Greek: Φοινίκη, Phoiníkē) was an ancient Semitic-speaking thalassocratic civilization that originated in the Levant region of the eastern Mediterranean, specifically modern Lebanon.[6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sealand_Dynasty) It was concentrated along the coast of Lebanon and included some coastal areas of Syria and northern Palestine reaching as far north as Arwad and as far south as Acre and possibly Gaza.[8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramesses_II#Battle_against_Sherden_sea_pirates)[10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherden#Early_historical_references) At its height between 1100 and 200 BC, Phoenician civilization spread across the Mediterranean, from Cyprus to the Iberian Peninsula.

So therefore, shipping could not have possibly been a creation solely of the Phoenicians, though it is possible the Phoenicians were the Sherden.

Who the Sherden were, and why they had taken to the sea's would be theory, not fact. Whether it be due to the Minoan eruption. They were definitely advanced when it came to Seafaring.

However there is evidence of long distance shipping which pre-dates the Sea-peoples.

I also do not agree that contemporary historians are of the opinion that even the most ancient boating was necessarily only conducted close to the shore.

Though, they have no archaeological evidence that it was not, common sense might suggest otherwise.

**History**

[History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boat#History)

> Boats have served as transportation since the earliest times.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dugout_canoe) Circumstantial evidence, such as the early settlement of Australia over 40,000 years ago, findings in Crete dated 130,000 years ago,[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pesse_canoe) and in Flores dated to 900,000 years ago

**Origins**

[Origins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aboriginal_Australians#Origins)

> The ancestors of present-day Aboriginal Australians migrated from Asia by sea during the Pleistocene era

Comment: I don't know who downvoted, while the answer is not succinct, it has a lot of useful pointers. The Battle of Ramesses II against the Sherden people may hint at an earliest known sufficient seafaring ability to cross the Mediterranean with an army (not following the coast), though the details on wikipedia are insufficient.

Comment: @tkruse If you go to threads made by me in Meta, you will see why i am being downvoted. It is because when i first came here i got a bit ahead of myself and asked too many questions about things which pertain to ancient ancient history and cannot be easily answered. And i got a negative reaction. However the owners of the site are aware that i became the victim of vote targetting. It will probably take a while to get over.